# Android mysql - PHP login

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have a problem with my Java. When I try to log in first it shows "*Loading Data*" than a huge dot (something like progress bar) and it doesn't log in.

I have tried multiple hosts for the database and php files, and used php files with another project. Maybe there's something I've missed.

When I change the code to simply log in with access to a text file or xml, everything works perfectly. Using for coding Android Studio.

Another site told me to try:

1. Access your page without logging in.
2. Post data without logging in
3. Write module to login usign post data.

But I kinda don't know how.

```js
package com.example.test.test;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText Email, Password;
    Button Signin ;
    String PasswordHolder, EmailHolder;
    String finalResult ;
    String HttpURL = "192.168.0.101/login.php";
    Boolean CheckEditText ;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    HttpParse httpParse = new HttpParse();
    public static final String UserEmail = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        Signin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);

        Signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();

                if(CheckEditText){

                    UserLoginFunction(EmailHolder, PasswordHolder);

                }
                else {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please fill all form fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        });
    }
    public void CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot(){

        EmailHolder = Email.getText().toString();
        PasswordHolder = Password.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(EmailHolder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(PasswordHolder))
        {
            CheckEditText = false;
        }
        else {

            CheckEditText = true ;
        }
    }

    public void UserLoginFunction(final String email, final String password){

        class UserLoginClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data");
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                hashMap.put("email",params[0]);

                hashMap.put("password",params[1]);

                finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpURL);

                return finalResult;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

                super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                if(httpResponseMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Data Matched")){

                    finish();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test.class);

                    intent.putExtra(UserEmail,email);

                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                else{

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,httpResponseMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }


        }

        UserLoginClass userLoginClass = new UserLoginClass();

        userLoginClass.execute(email,password);
    }

}
```

Comment: This might be too obvious, but have you tried adding "http://" to your `HttpURL` string?

Comment: Yes. Still not working.

Comment: You need to use an HTTP client for the post method like HttpURLConnection or Retrofit, and also check if you have added proper permissions in the manifest.

Comment: url = new URL(192.168.0.101/login.php);
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

      connection.setRequestMethod("GET");                                                                  Like this?